# Faster Way to Color All Occurences in a RichTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, text-coloring

I have a RichTextBox, and there are about more than 1000 occurrences of a specified search string.

I use the following function to color all the occurrences:

```
public void ColorAll(string s)
{
    rtbxContent.BeginUpdate();

    int start = 0, current = 0;
    RichTextBoxFinds options = RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase;
    start = rtbxContent.Find(s, start, options);
    while (start >= 0)
    {
        rtbxContent.SelectionStart  = start;
        rtbxContent.SelectionLength = s.Length;
        rtbxContent.SelectionColor     = Color.Red;
        rtbxContent.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;

        current = start + s.Length;
        if (current < rtbxContent.TextLength)
            start = rtbxContent.Find(s, current, options);
        else
            break;
    }

    rtbxContent.EndUpdate();
}
```

But I found it's very slow.

However, if I color all the occurrences of another word, which has less number of occurrences in the same text, I found it's very fast.

So I guess the slowness is from (these two line might get UI refresh involved):

```
    rtbxContent.SelectionColor     = Color.Red;
    rtbxContent.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Is there a faster way of doing the same job, such as, I do the coloring in the memory, and then I display the result at one-go?

Do I make myself clear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a faster way.

Use regex to find the matches then highlight in the richtextbox

```
    if (this.tBoxFind.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
               this.richTBox.SuspendLayout();
               this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

           string s = this.richTBox.Text;
           System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection mColl = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s, this.tBoxFind.Text);

           foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match g in mColl)
           {
                  this.richTBox.SelectionColor = Color.White;
                  this.richTBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;

                  this.richTBox.Select(g.Index, g.Length);
           }
   }
   finally
   {
         this.richTBox.ResumeLayout();
         this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The amount of time it takes is directly proportional to the number of occurances.

It is probably the Find that is using the most time. You could replace this line:

```
    start = rtbxContent.Find(s, start + s.Length, options);
```

with this:

```
    start = rtbxContent.Find(s, current, options);
```

Since you have computed current to equal start + s.Length

You could also store s.Length is a variable so you do not need to count all the characters in a string each time. The same goes for rtbxContent.TextLength.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. I did forget to replace "start+s.Length" with current :-)

Answer (score 0):

The string search is linear. If you find `Find` method to be slow, maybe you can use third party tool to do the searching for you. All you need is index of the pattern in a string.

Maybe [this will help you](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/fastsearch.html). You should time the difference and use the faster one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm not sure whether my guess is right or not. I don't think the "Find" method is the main reason causing it so slow.  I think it might be the UI update/refresh make it slow.

Comment: Then why don't you time the individual code pieces? You'll know where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track that Winforms' slow RichTextBox implementation is to blame. You also did well to use the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods (I'm guessing you took those from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26088349/848344)?). But alas, that isn't enough.

A couple of solutions:

1: Try writing the RTF directly to the textbox. This is a fairly messy, complicated format, but luckily, I have created an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29786048/848344) which will do the trick.

2: This highly rated external project also looks well worth a look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

Comment: RichTextBox does not allow setting back color via RTF, so #1 won't work.