# Change Font.Size in a RichTextBox .SelectionFont with multiple FontFamily

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

How can I change the `Font.Size` in a `RichTextBox .SelectionFont` (which has two or three different `FontFamily`), without affecting the `FontFamily`and the `FontStyle`

This one works fine, if I have only one Font.Family

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont.FontFamily, 12);
```

But, if I have more, it throws nullexception.

Comment: Consider using this great textbox component: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

Comment: RichTextBox.SelectionFont returns null if there are different fonts selected. You´ll have to write logic using RichTextBox.Select to change around your selection and set the Fonts individually for each Font.Family

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1563724/848344) from the question: "[Reset RTF in RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268009/reset-rtf-in-richtextbox/29786048)" may help you. I quote:

> More you ask?
>
> I use most of this via a small utility class that wraps this for all the styles and font changes. This way you can change font-size and not change font name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Check the answer by LarsTech here:

[Changing font for richtextbox without losing formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306184/changing-font-for-richtextbox-without-losing-formatting)

You'll find properties such as `SelectionFontName`, `SelectionFontSize`, ...